# Redirect with parameters. NoReverseMatch at /test/

Tags: django

**views.py:**

```
def demo(request, **kwargs):
    print response
    ......

def test(request):
    ......
    kwargs = {'response': response}
    return redirect('demo', **kwargs)
```

**urls.py:**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from django.contrib.sitemaps.views import sitemap


urlpatterns = patterns('clients.views',
    url(r'^test/', 'test', name='test'),
    url(r'^demo/', 'demo', name='demo'),

)
```

Why I have this error:

> NoReverseMatch at /test/
>
> Reverse for 'demo' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments
> '{'response': {u'status': u'ok'}}' not found.
>
> Request Method:   POST Request URL:   http ://127.0.0.1:8000/test/

Comment: `return redirect('demo')`

Comment: @falsetru Why? I need to have access to `response` in my `demo` view. How to add parametr?

Comment: First, the response variable does exist in your demo view (use kwargs.get('response')). Then which version of Django are you using ?

Comment: Have you tried to reverse it from the shell ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using the `redirect()` shortcut you're actually doing a `HttpResponseRedirect()` and therefore need *not* to include the response in your `kwargs`.

Furthermore if you would like to redirect with keyworded arguments then the call would be

```
redirect('/myurl/', momma="im comin' home")
```

or

```
redirect('/myurl/', kwargs={'loads_a_kwargs':'cowboy'})
```

The error you're getting is because your regexp `url(r'^demo/', 'demo', name='demo')` *does not* accept any parameters. Also, normally you would end all your url regexes with `$` to denote that the capturing should stop.

Comment: How to correct my url regexp to accept parametrs from `redirect('/myurl/', kwargs={'loads_a_kwargs':'cowboy'})` ?

Comment: `url(r'^demo/(?P<loads_a_kwargs>\w+)/$', 'demo', name='demo')` and don't forget to update your `demo` view with `def demo(loads_a_kwargs, request):`

Answer (score 0):

Thats error simply been raised not from your `test` view but from your `demo` view. As per url reverse matching .. demo url must match to the demo view function parameters.

for example : url : `demo/` should be `demo/<response>`

And In case you don't want to change the url pattern then make your response as `GET` parameter to `demo` view.

Answer (score 0):

When you say `redirect('demo', **kwargs)`, internally its trying to find the urlpattern `demo/(?P<response>\d+)`. Actually it could be either `\d+` or `\w+` or whatever. But you don't have this urlpattern defined and so its failing.

So, it will pass if you define such url pattern. But another problem with your code is that `response` in `kwargs` is a dictionary and there is no way you can capture a dictionary in the url pattern.

Any particular reason you want to redirect to demo along with `status` code?

Answer (score 0):

NoReverseMatch Exception Occurs when a matching URL in your URLconf cannot be identified based on the parameters you have given. Refer the django Docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/exceptions/#noreversematch

I am looking at your `url.py` You didn't included `$`

`url(r'^test/$', 'test', name='test'),`